# How do I require client certificates with a specific username / password in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, authentication, ssl-certificate

I have several clients certificates that my Apache httpd server requires clients to have (made using the instructions at http://www.garex.net/apache/). I would like to have an authentication that also authenticates and allows only a client certificate to match a username/password combination.

For example, if I have two client certificates with CN `user1` and `user2` and .htpasswd file

```
user1:passwordA
user2:passwordB
```

I would like something like

```
SSLUserName %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}
AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

However, trying this results in 500 errors. What can I do?

Comment: hi @cm007 did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

The error 500 is due to wrong`SSLUserName` syntax — it should be written without `%{...}`:

```
SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
```

But actually if you want to require basic auth and certificate name to match, you should remove `SSLUserName` (so that `mod_ssl` would not touch `REMOTE_USER`) and use:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq %{REMOTE_USER}
```

---

Another option which might work better when used in the config file directly (not in `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} !=%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I have
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    <Location />
    AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
    SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq %{REMOTE_USER}
    </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
but this gives a 403 error, and the authentication dialog never appears to the client. If I move the four lines about auth outside of the Location tag, then Apache says AuthName not allowed here.

Comment: Is `SSLVerifyClient require` also specified? You may also try a mod_rewrite variant added to the answer.